# How can I implement server-side processing to my datatables using a json file?

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

This is my datatable that works with a json file:

```
var table = $('.table').DataTable({
     "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50,100, -1], [10, 25, 50,100, "All"]],
     "pageLength": 10,
     "data":{{ output.data|raw }},
```

It works well like this.

To get the datatable faster I added this lines:

```
var table = $('.table').DataTable({
     "serverSide": true,
     "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50,100, -1], [10, 25, 50,100, "All"]],
     "pageLength": 10,
     "data":{{ output.data|raw }},
     "processing": true,
```

Now I get the error

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON
>   response

The json comes directly from a json file with data.

Comment: If you set `serverSide: true` then you should not use `data`. Provide the URL to the JSON file in the `ajax` property. See the [documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I removed data and added ajax with the correct link to the json file, but it is no datatable is loaded now :(

Comment: Check the console for errors

Comment: The error is `TypeError: c is undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation on the `serverSide` option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide) explains:

> DataTables has two fundamental modes of operation:
>
> - Client-side processing - where filtering, paging and sorting calculations are all performed in the web-browser.
> - Server-side processing - where filtering, paging and sorting calculations are all performed by a server.

`serverSide: true` means that the raw data, as a whole, does not exist on the client. The client only holds sorted and paginated views of the data that are sent from an HTTP endpoint made to communicate those pages to a client.

If you send all the data to the client, you probably don't intend to use server-side processing.

If your problem is that sorting and paginating the data is too slow (because your data consists of many hundreds or thousands of records), then you probably do want switch to server-side processing. The first step is to stop specifying a `data` option and instead use an `ajax` option with a target URL. Then you need to write a server-side endpoint at the URL that performs the necessary transformations when requested. See the [DataTables example documentation on server side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side) to get started.

Comment: you mean when I use this   `"serverSide": true,
  "ajax": "data.json",`it should work

Comment: @peace_love If `data.json` is a server-side endpoint that is prepared to alter its responses based on the parameters sent to it, then yes. Otherwise, no. When you say `ajax": "data.json"` you are telling the DataTables client to send a request like `data.json?start=10&length=5&...` and expects back a response like `{"draw":4,"recordsTotal":57,"recordsFiltered":57,"data":[ ... ]}` where the `data` field is a rendered, trimmed and sorted view of your data on the server. Have you written server-side code to do data processing? If not, you do not intend to use DataTable's server-side processing.

Comment: Ah, now I understand, very good explaination. my data.json starts like this: `[{"id":536,"name":"Alfred",...` So I have to add the format into the file right? and than it should work?